# How to remove laravel 5.2 directory name from url after hosting it online

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-5

I have laravel 5.2 project developed.I have hosted it online

I access that project using the url

www.mydomainname.com/laravelproj/admin

Here I don't want the "laravelproj" i.e project directory name , I just want

www.mydomainname.com/admin  to be opened

I am unable to change the settings in .htacess properly.
Anyone please assist me in doing so.

My .htaccess file

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^.env - [F,L,NC]        

</IfModule>
```

My directory structure for project

[image]

My routes.php file contents are

```
 //Routes for all admin control panel
 Route::get('/admin','Admin\LoginController@viewlogin');
 Route::post('/admin/login','Admin\LoginController@checklogin');

 Route::group(['middleware' => ['admins']], function () 
 {

Route::get('/admin/dashboard','Admin\AdminController@dashboard');
Route::get('/admin/logout','Admin\LoginController@logout');
Route::resource('/admin/movies','Admin\MovieController');
Route::resource('/admin/states','Admin\StateController');
Route::resource('/admin/cities','Admin\CityController');
Route::resource('/admin/tax','Admin\TaxController');
Route::resource('/admin/smsgateway','Admin\SmsgatewayController');
Route::resource('/admin/smtpgateway','Admin\SmtpgatewayController');
Route::resource('/admin/paymentgateway','Admin\PaymentgatewayController');
Route::resource('/admin/news','Admin\NewsController');
Route::resource('/admin/promotion','Admin\PromotionController');
Route::resource('/admin/staff','Admin\StaffController');
Route::get('/admin/staff/resetpass/{id}','Admin\StaffController@resetpass');



});
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure how you manage to run laravel in www.mydomainname.com/laravelproj/admin - the laravel public folder is supposed to be the root of your website ( so basically www.mydomainname.com - to manage what you want to achieve you should probably create a subdomain and link the public folder to it's root. ( admin.mydomainname.com )

Comment: I have removed public from url

Comment: You will need to give us way more information on your setup. Maybe make a screenshot of your ftp structure and add your routes.php file

Comment: I am sorry for that, I have edited my question .

Comment: nonononono please don't ever do this. the public folder exists for a good reason. If you work locally then use virtualhosts to create something like my-laravel.dev and let this point directly to htdocs/laravelproject/public/ but dont put public files into the actual app - this is highly insecure. If you work on a host and this is your main website then just change the internal routing to go into /public or add a symlink

Comment: oh , i read some articles to remove public from url and they suggested to do like this.. now public is removed from url but I am facing this problem... okay if i do reverse of what i did now then will it work fine without any problem....

Comment: As i already said, you should change stuff at your hosting provider and locally you should use virtualhosts

Comment: ok Thanks I will keep this in mind

Answer (score 0):

Go to app/Http/routes.php in the directory where you installed Laravel and just remove `laravelproj` from the routes. It should look something like this:

```
Route::get('laravelproj/admin', 'PagesController@admin');
```

change it to

```
Route::get('admin', 'PagesController@admin');
```

If you installed your Laravel project into an extra subfolder on your server, then, depending on how big your project is, it may be a good idea to reinstall it again into the public root directory on your server. Otherwise you may be facing multiple issues with databases and libraries you might want to install in the future.

Comment: No i have not used anywhere laravelproj in routes, actually i have already removed public from url , and hosted it online